# UIButton width is 50% of UIView's width iOS

Tags: ios, uiview, uibutton, storyboard, xcode6

I am new to Storyboard environment.

How to set `UIButton's` width is to 50% of `UIView's` width using AutoLayout Constraints in Storyboard in XCode6

Can any one tell me how to implement this?

Comment: Use align & pin constraints , take the width as percentage

Comment: Click the button, hold the control key and drag to the view, select equal width, then modify the constraint's aspect ratio to 1:0.5.

Answer (score 14):

1. select you button and superview

[image]

2. make pin

[image]

3. select constraints

[image]

4. Reverse both items and set multiplier to 0.5

[image]

5. select only button and set horizontal align

[image]

**Done!**

I recommend using Masonry/SnapKit libraries from github